# what ad server works with titanium appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, ads

i would like to show ads on my titanium mobile app. I have had a look at the modules in the titanium marketplace, and have not found any that worked - the closest was millennial media's, that showed a wonky-sized ad.

Does anyone out there have any ads showing on their mobile device, and if so, how did they get the ads showing? I'm not tied to any ad server.

I am using titanium 3.4.0

I want the ad module, preferably, to work on both android and ios.

The best answer would have the module with some form of clear documentation. It can be from github or the appcelerator marketplace or anywhere, really.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If , i am not wrong you are talking about this Admob Module :

This one for android as well as iOS.

[MarketPlace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4961?1583446704#!overview)

Thanks,

Comment: Plus one for the effort, but this module did not work for me, and the reviews of it indicate it wont work for anybody.

Comment: @bharal : i didnt test that in latest , but that work fine in 3.2.0

[https://medium.com/titanium-templates/integrate-admob-with-appcelerator-titanium-34f081d4ad30](https://medium.com/titanium-templates/integrate-admob-with-appcelerator-titanium-34f081d4ad30)